# Yield from C# to C++, dealing with containers

Tags: c++, oop, stl, containers

Actually, I have a design question here. Its very simple but the point is:

I have one C++ class that has a STL vector declared as a private member. But the clients of that class need to iterate over this vector.

In C# we have a very handy statement, the Yield, that in cases like that, you write a function returning an IEnumerable and it "yields" you a nice way to iterate over a private container inside that class.

I'm just trying to find an elegant solution for C++, instead of using methods like GetValue(int idx).

Any suggestions?

Example:

```
class Fat
{
   public:
      Fat();
   // some code here ...

   private:
      void LoadSectors(SECT startPoint);
      std::vector<SECT>sectors;

};

class Storage
{
   public:
      Storage(string CompoundFile);

      //For example, this method will receive a ref to my fat system and iterate over
      //the fat array in order to read every sector. 
      LoadStrem(Fat& fat);

};
```

This is far simple example.

Comment: What is so inelegant about GetValue(index)?

Comment: @Ed: that you are then bound forever to an indexable container.  The client code doesn't need to know how the elements are contained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no syntactic sugar in C++ analogous to `yield` in C#. If you want to create a class, instances of which should be iterable in the same way stock STL collections are, then you have to implement an iterator for your class, expose it as `::iterator` on your type, and provide `begin()` and `end()` member functions.

Comment: The vector already implements an iterator. You can just do `typedef vector<SECT>::const_iterator const_iterator;` and (perhaps) `typedef vector<SECT>::iterator iterator;`

Answer (score 4):

You can either create an accessor function which returns a reference (or preferably const reference) to the vector, or you can create `begin()` and `end()` accessor functions which return the appropriate vector iterators.

Answer (score 2):

It always hurts when you need to publish the innards of your class...

You may be able to solve it by providing algorithms as the stl does: provide a `foreach` function on the object's interface.

```
class S { 
   std::vector<int> v;

public:
   //... and some methods to populate the vector

   template< typename F > F& foreach( F& f ) { 
      return std::for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), f );
   }

};
```

This way, the class remains 'closed', but you have the flexibility you need.  You can also add a `copy` function, and maybe a `transform`; these are the ones I most frequently need.

Comment: There may be similar reasons to publish the "innards" as `std::vector` publishes its "innards" - that is, it could be essentially a container class just happening to use a `std::vector` as the underlying type. P.S Exposing the contents of the vector won't expose the vector itself.

Comment: Er, this isn't what the STL does. Quite the contrary. What the STL *doesn't* do is couple the container and the iteration algorithm.

Comment: @jalf: you're right: that would mean `vector.foreach( ... )`.  I meant providing _algorithms_ as the stl does.

Answer (score 1):

Let your class expose iterators.

```
class Fat
{
   public:
    typedef std::vector<SECT>::iterator iterator;

    iterator begin() { return sectors.begin(); }
    iterator end() { return sectors.end(); }

      Fat();
   // some code here ...

   private:
      void LoadSectors(SECT startPoint);
      std::vector<SECT>sectors;
```

Then the surrounding code can traverse the elements of the vector freely, through just a pair of iterators.